# GeneratedValue does not get a unique new value

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have my hibernate configured as follows:

```
Entity
@Table (name = "statuspaatelling")
public class StatusPaaTelling {

private Long statusPaaTellingId;

@Id
@Column(name = "statusPaaTellingID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
public Long getStatusPaaTellingId() {
    return statusPaaTellingId;
}
```

When I was creating new elements it worked perfectly, but suddenly now it creates values that already exist. And I cant create new elements since i get duplicate entries for my Primary key. I am using a MySQL database.

```
Duplicate entry '3155220' for key 'PRIMARY'
Error Code: 1062
Call: INSERT INTO statuspaatelling (statusPaaTellingID, something) VALUES(?, ?)
```

I think it might first happened when i imported a dump of the database and switched to using that. I've also tried switching back with no luck, but they have the exact same setup so I should not matter. Anyone has any ideas why the GeneratedValue suddenly didn't work?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably hitting [this MySQL bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=20786) (opened 7 years ago!!!). If you read the comments, someone posted a workaround using `sed` to fix the MySQL dump, e.g.:

```
sed -i -e 's/ AUTO_INCREMENT=[0-9]\+//' mydump.sql
```

You could also pipe the output of `mysqldump` through that `sed` command.

Comment: Yes my dump did include AUTO_INCREMENT=xxx. And I got removed it by using the sed command, however it is still creating existing values.

Comment: Do you restart the process running Hibernate after you import the data?

Answer (score -1):

Have you declared the column as Auto Increment?

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

If not declared the column as auto increment, please follow the below link:

[ALTER table - adding AUTOINCREMENT in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6957370/alter-table-adding-autoincrement-in-mysql)

Comment: Yes I have. CREATE TABLE `statuspaatelling` (
  `statusOppdatert` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `statusPaaTellingID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT. I has worked before, just stopped working a day ago.