# My input will not insert information to my database/ Fatal Error

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysql-workbench

I have a mock database concerning information about students, and the subjects they are taking.

I wanted to create a code that would let me register new subjects and link two columns to other tables with a foreign key. however, it doesn't work and I get an error message.

I have tested my connection several times, and it works. the select code works directly in mysql workbench. Below is my code and a picture of the database.

The error messages i get:

> **Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'mysqli_sql_exception' with message 'Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'' in C:\wamp\www\oveove.php on
>   line 159 ( ! ) mysqli_sql_exception: Duplicate entry '0' for key
>   'PRIMARY' in C:\wamp\www\oveove.php on line 159**

```
<form method="post">
  <form method="post">
  <input type="text" name="fagnavn" placeholder="skriv inn fagets navn">
  <input type="text" name="type" value="skriv inn fagklassen">
  <select  name="lærer">


  <?php
$sql="select * from lærer";
$resultat = $kobling->query($sql);
while ($rad = $resultat->fetch_assoc()) {
  $lærerfnavn=$rad["fnavn"];
  $lærerenavn=$rad["enavn"];
  $idlærer= $rad["idlærer"];
  $heltnavn = $lærerfnavn. " ". $lærerenavn;
echo "<option value='$idlærer'> $heltnavn </option>";

}

   ?>
   </select>
   <select  name="studieret">
     <?php
$sql= "select * from studieret";
$resultat= $kobling->query($sql);

while ($rad= $resultat->fetch_assoc()) {
  $leder= $rad["leder"];
  $id=$rad["idstudieretning"];
  echo "<option value='$id'> $leder </option>";
}


      ?>

 </select>
 <input type="submit" name="sendinn2" value="Send inn">
</form>
<?php
if (isset($_POST["sendinn2"])) {

$fag= $_POST["fagnavn"];
$type= $_POST["type"];
$lærer=$_POST["lærer"];
$studieret=$_POST["studieret"];

  $sql="insert into fag (fagnavn, type, idlærer, idstudieretning) values ('$fag', '$type', '$lærer', '$studieret')";
  echo "$sql";
  if ($kobling->query($sql)) {
    echo "kobblingen $sql ble gjennomført";
  }
  else {
    echo "det var et problem med kobling $sql($kobling->error_message)";
  }
}
 ?>
```

[image: database]

Comment: Your trying to insert a record with a duplicate key. Did you forget to turn on auto increment yon your Primary key?

Comment: Also, Your script is at risk for [SQL Injection Attacks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/). Use [prepared statements](https://bobby-tables.com/php). Even [escaping](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/) the string is not safe!

Comment: You have only one insert statement in your code. It is into fag table. And in that statement you do not insert idfag. Is there a sequence for that column that enters the value in the primary key ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6957370/alter-table-adding-autoincrement-in-mysql Here is how...

Comment: thanks, i figured it out. however now i got another problem: Uncaught exception 'mysqli_sql_exception' with message 'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`karakterer`.`fag`, CONSTRAINT `FK_fag_studieret` FOREIGN KEY (`idStudieretning`) REFERENCES `studieret` (`idstudieretning`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)' in C:\wamp\www\oveove.php on line 159

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to take a look at the table `fag` where the code is trying to insert some data into that table, because you probably have defined one field as primary key but when you do the insert statement you are not inserting that field, and if that field has not been setted as autoincrement, the DB fills it with default value, 0 if it's an integer field.

Comment: this solved my original problem, but uncovered another.. Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'mysqli_sql_exception' with message 'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`karakterer`.`fag`, CONSTRAINT `FK_fag_studieret` FOREIGN KEY (`idStudieretning`) REFERENCES `studieret` (`idstudieretning`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)' in C:\wamp\www\oveove.php on line 159

Comment: Did you do an echo of this sentece `$sql="insert into fag (fagnavn, type, idlærer, idStudieretning) values ('$fag', '$type', '$lærer', '$studieret')";` to see what are really the values that you are passing when the form do the post?

Comment: That's because the column **idStudieretning** is a foreign key from the table **studieret**. That means that in your table **studieret** must exist a row with **idstudieretning** column equal to your **idStudieretning** value before you can insert in your **fag** table

Comment: @nacho That's exactly the error. I told him to do an echo, because if you look at the code he posted, is taking the values from the select that is previously loaded with the table `studieret` values. In that way he can ensures that the values loaded in the SQL sentence are correct.

Comment: @JonatanRuiz it returns: insert into fag (fagnavn, type, idlærer, idStudieretning) values ('Mattematikk', 'Realfag', '3', '')

Comment: on a closer look at the code, i think the problem is that in the load of the select when the variable `$id=$rad["idStudieretning"];` is assigned, the index of the array is 'idStudieretning' but in the capture of the DB Schema, the field is named `'idstudieretning'` without a capital **S**

Comment: @nacho does that mean the columns must have the same name?

Comment: @JonatanRuiz thank you, but it did not change anything. updating my code now

Comment: @line2509 that's it, if you change this `$id=$rad["idStudieretning"];` for this `$id=$rad["idstudieretning"];`it will work fine.

Comment: @line2509 ok do one more test, load the page on the navigator, if you are on chrome right-click on the studieretning select, click on inspect, and look on the inspector the raw code of the page, to look if the php effectively load the id on the value of every option

Comment: it will show something like this

<select name="select">
<option value="value1">Value 1</option>
<option selected="" value="value2">Value 2</option>
<option value="value3">Value 3</option>
</select>

here you can check if the id is loaded

Comment: i got three unique values (1,2,3) and the corresponding value. Everything seems fine

Comment: @line2509 ok put this `var_dump($_POST);` after this line `if (isset($_POST["sendinn2"])) {` it will let you know what values POST is getting.

Comment: @JonatanRuiz i edited my database so that all columns were named the same. now it works. thank you for your time and effort

Comment: No, the columns don't need to have the same name. What it means is that, when you insert a row in flag table, you set a value for the column idStudieretning (in your examples before this comment, you set '' as value (that is not NULL, is an empty string)). But, as idStudieretning is a FOREIGN KEY, it needs to have a row in the studieret table that has the same value for the column idstudieretning, so you can say **fag.idStudieretning=studieret.idstudieretning**

Comment: oh i see. so fag.idstudieretning needs to have value 1 if it islinked to studieret.idstudieretning with value 1? and it has to have a value, because i set it to NN?

Comment: last question, i updated my page a lot of times to get this to work. that means that a lot of rows have been added to my tables, even if the input fields were empty. any reasons for this, and any way to fix it?

Comment: @line2509 you have to validate before to make the SQL insert statement that the variables $fag $type $lærer and $studieret are not empty, if this are empty you must not execute the sql query.