# How to add auto_increment field to a table with huge data?

Tags: mysql

Say there's a table `table_test`, and there're about 10M rows data in the table. And I want to add a auto_increment field like `key` to do some pagination work. What is the best way to make it work?

the table stucture as below:

```
# table_test

+---------------------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                                 | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| ad_id                                 | int(64)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| account_id                            | varchar(64)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| country                               | varchar(64)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| image_hash                            | varchar(64)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------------------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+



| table_test | CREATE TABLE `table_test` (
  `ad_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `account_id` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `country` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `image_hash` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`country`),
  KEY `account_id` (`account_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 |
```

> update:

change `id` to `ad_id`, and `ad_id` here is unique key togather with field `country`, so `ad_id` itself may be duplicated.

Comment: Id has duplicates?

Comment: @Nae Yes, It means `ad_id` here, and It's unique togather with `country`. I've updated my question above

Comment: Doesnt at all answer the question asked but make your pagination based on last row seen. Eh next page is last_seen=something & rows = 10 you can keep this structure then. Downside is replication doesn't look like it's going to be effective for this structure

Comment: @exussum Thanks for your replying but i'm not fully understood of your suggestion.  Could you please make it more clear for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd go:

```
-- drop PK as AUTO increment demands being the PK
ALTER TABLE table_test DROP PRIMARY KEY;
-- add Id as PK and the first column
ALTER TABLE table_test ADD Id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY FIRST;
-- make sure the old PK is unique
ALTER TABLE table_test ADD CONSTRAINT table_test_uk UNIQUE (ad_id, country);
```

or perhaps:

```
CREATE TABLE table_test2 LIKE table_test;
ALTER TABLE table_test2 DROP PRIMARY KEY;
-- add Id as PK and the first column
ALTER TABLE table_test2 ADD Id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY FIRST;
-- make sure the old PK is unique
ALTER TABLE table_test2 ADD CONSTRAINT table_test2_uk UNIQUE (ad_id, country);
INSERT INTO table_test2(ad_id, account_id, country, image_hash)
SELECT ad_id, account_id, country, image_hash FROM table_test;
DROP TABLE table_test;
RENAME TABLE table_test2 TO table_test;
```

Comment: Thanks for relpying, the operation seemed to cost a lot of time   and How can I speed it up ?

Comment: @jiaJimmy Added an alternative approach.

Answer (score 0):

Just Alter your table

```
ALTER TABLE table_test CHANGE id id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can already use the 'id' column as an auto increment (unless you are using UUID or some other strategy).

You can check the following answer on how to alter the table to add auto increment to a table:
[ALTER table - adding AUTOINCREMENT in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6957370/alter-table-adding-autoincrement-in-mysql)

Edit: 
If you wish to add a new column that will be auto incremented , you can use the following:
ALTER TABLE table_test ADD id INT AUTO_INCREMENT;