# How to Auto Increment the Primary Key of wp-posts in Wordpress?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-gutenberg

I have migrated my WordPress website to another hosting server, and now I cannot create new posts. I have tried these methods to fix it but couldn't get success:

1. enable/disable plugins
2. change the theme
3. check the syntax of wp-config
4. database repair
5. contact hosting

I came to know that after importing the WordPress database to the new hosting server, some of my primary keys got disturbed. Now, I want to edit the table "wp_posts" and make its primary key (which is "id") to auto increment. Following is the SQL query but it's not working:

```
ALTER TABLE wp_posts AUTO_INCREMENT id = 1;
```

Following is the screenshot of the existing wp-posts table:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvBHF.png)

Comment: What error you getting while creating post? Have you checked error logs?

Comment: i think there is some issue while exporting your SQL dump. Please let us know which sql server you are using ? phymyadmin ??

Comment: @AqibJaved I am using Cpanel and PHPMyAdmin. When I click on "new post" in the admin panel of WordPress, it opens an empty white page.

Comment: `ALTER TABLE wp_posts AUTO_INCREMENT id = 1;` - I don't think that is correct syntax, the `id` does not belong in there, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/6957705/1427878 And resetting autoincrement to 1 probably makes little sense, when you have existing posts with IDs 3, 7, 8, etc. already. Delete the top row with that extremely high ID value, then find the maximum of the "legit" post ids that are left, and set autoincrement to that plus 1.